# js function - delegate after creating html element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```
<table>
    <tr id="firstaut">
       <td>Author:</td>
       <td>
          <input class="auts" name="name" />
       </td>
       <td>
          <button class="aut_button" type="button">delete</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2">
          <a onclick="addmore()"> + add more name</a>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>


$(function(){
   $('.aut_button').on('click',function(){
     alert('test');
   });
});
function addmore(){
   $("<tr id='firstaut'><td>Author:</td><td><input class='auts' name='name'/></td><td><button class='aut_button' type='button'>delete</button></td></tr>")
          .insertAfter('#firstaut').delegate('.aut_button');           
}
```

If i click on newly added `delete` button, it is not `alerting`. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `on` with the other overload,

```
$(function(){
   $('table').on('click', '.aut_button' ,function(){
     alert('test');
   });
});
```

Please read [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to know more about `event delegation`.

Comment: i dont click on table, why ``on()`` on table?

Comment: you have to delegate the click event on a static parent element.